# Google Measurement Protocol Timing hit type not shown in Real-time report

Tags: google-analytics

I'm in the process of adding support for Google Measurement Protocol in my macOS desktop app. Doing pageviews and events works fine. However, I'm not sure that my timing hit type works fine.

When I send

https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&t=timing&tid=UA-xxx-1&cid=58xxx&utc=archive&utv=bla&utt=4

I get the usual pixel back. The Hit Builder also validates fine. However, for pageviews and events I see something in Real-Time report of Google Analytics. This doesn't happen for the timing hit type.

I've tried with the debug url and got back the following:

```
{
  "hitParsingResult": [ {
    "valid": true,
    "parserMessage": [ ],
    "hit": "/debug/collect?v=1\u0026t=timing\u0026tid=UA-xxx-1\u0026cid=58xxx\u0026utc=archive\u0026utv=bla\u0026utt=4"
  } ],
  "parserMessage": [ {
    "messageType": "INFO",
    "description": "Found 1 hit in the request."
  } ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Real Time Report is not supposed to display timing hits. Check your regular GA timing reports

Comment: Thanks, yes, this seems to be the case.